# How can I set the heading of a block in a QTextEdit in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt5

I am trying to integrate a WYSIWYG HTML editor in my PyQT5 application. I have a tool bar with a combobox with several block styles and a QTextEdit. This is the code I have as of now to implement the heading styles (I have only added the relevant sections):

```
self.text_edit.cursorPositionChanged.connect(self.check_newline)
self.bg_color_picker_action.triggered.connect(self.bg_pick_color)

    def toggle_bold(self):
        format = QTextCharFormat()
        format.setFontWeight(QFont.Bold if self.bold_action.isChecked() else QFont.Normal)
        cursor = self.text_edit.textCursor()
        cursor.mergeCharFormat(format)
        self.text_edit.mergeCurrentCharFormat(format)
        self.text_edit.setFocus()
        self.text_edit.document().setModified(True)

    # Check if a new line has started, and if so make the style a paragraph
    def check_newline(self):
        cursor = self.text_edit.textCursor()
        if cursor.positionInBlock() == 0:
            fmt = cursor.blockFormat()
            fmt.setHeadingLevel(0)
            self.heading_combo.setCurrentIndex(0)
            cursor.mergeBlockFormat(fmt)
            self.text_edit.textCursor().mergeBlockFormat(fmt)

    def apply_heading(self):
        cursor = self.text_edit.textCursor()
        fmt = cursor.blockFormat()
        if self.heading_combo.currentText() == "Heading 1":
            fmt.setHeadingLevel(1)
        elif self.heading_combo.currentText() == "Heading 2":
            fmt.setHeadingLevel(2)
        elif self.heading_combo.currentText() == "Heading 3":
            fmt.setHeadingLevel(3)
        elif self.heading_combo.currentText() == "Heading 4":
            fmt.setHeadingLevel(4)
        elif self.heading_combo.currentText() == "Heading 5":
            fmt.setHeadingLevel(5)
        elif self.heading_combo.currentText() == "Heading 6":
            fmt.setHeadingLevel(1)
        elif self.heading_combo.currentText() == "Paragraph":
            fmt.setHeadingLevel(0)

        self.text_edit.document().setModified(True)

        cursor.mergeBlockFormat(fmt)
        self.text_edit.textCursor().mergeBlockFormat(fmt)

        print(self.text_edit.toHtml())
```

I am printing the html each time the heading style is changed to help me in debugging, and it shows the proper changes to the html, with the correct tags i.e. `<h1>`, `<h2>`, `<p>` etc. However, this is not reflected in the QTextEdit unless I save it to a file, close the program and then open the file again. Setting the QTextEdit's html to its own html (`self.text_edit.setHtml(self.text_edit.toHtml())`) does not help, and also causes the undo history to be reset as well. Other changes, like bold, italics, and underline, do get shown immediately.

I have tried using:

1.`self.text_edit.setHtml(self.text_edit.toHtml())`

2. `self.text_edit.update()` and `self.text_edit.repaint`
3. ````
    new_fragment = QTextDocumentFragment(old_doc)
    new_html = new_fragment.toHtml()```
   ````

Answer (score 0):

It's explained in the documentation of [`setHeadingLevel()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextblockformat.html#setHeadingLevel):

> Setting the heading level does not automatically change the font size; however QTextDocumentFragment::fromHtml() sets both the heading level and the font size simultaneously.

This means that if you want to apply the heading programmatically, you need to explicitly set the font size adjustment.

The HTML parser does that by setting the `FontSizeAdjustment` QTextFormat property:

> Specifies the change in size given to the fontsize already set using FontPointSize or FontPixelSize.

Those values start with 3 for `H1` and decrease to -1 for `H5`.

Note that in order to get the proper character format, you need to get the cursor `charFormat` (which explicitly declares the font), not the `blockCharFormat`.

```py
    def apply_heading(self):
        cursor = self.text_edit.textCursor()
        fmt = cursor.charFormat()

        if self.heading_combo.currentText() == "Heading 1":
            fmt.setHeadingLevel(1)
        elif self.heading_combo.currentText() == "Heading 2":
            fmt.setHeadingLevel(2)
        elif self.heading_combo.currentText() == "Heading 3":
            fmt.setHeadingLevel(3)
        elif self.heading_combo.currentText() == "Heading 4":
            fmt.setHeadingLevel(4)
        elif self.heading_combo.currentText() == "Heading 5":
            fmt.setHeadingLevel(5)
        elif self.heading_combo.currentText() == "Heading 6":
            fmt.setHeadingLevel(1)
        elif self.heading_combo.currentText() == "Paragraph":
            fmt.setHeadingLevel(0)

        heading = fmt.headingLevel()
        if heading:
            adjust = max(-1, 4 - heading)
        else:
            adjust = 0
        fmt.setProperty(fmt.FontSizeAdjustment, adjust)

        cursor.select(cursor.BlockUnderCursor)
        cursor.mergeCharFormat(fmt)
```

As a suggestion, instead of using string comparison for the combo value, consider using the user data property of combo box items:

```py
    self.heading_combo.addItem("Heading 1", 1)
    self.heading_combo.addItem("Heading 2", 2)
    ...
    self.heading_combo.addItem("Paragraph", 0)
```

With that approach, you will immediately get the heading value using [`currentData()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#currentData-prop), without relying on the text that could possibly mismatch (for instance, when using translations, or because of a typo).

```py
    def apply_heading(self):
        cursor = self.text_edit.textCursor()
        fmt = cursor.charFormat()

        heading = self.heading_combo.currentData()
        fmt.setHeadingLevel(heading)
        # ...
```